# Writing an serialized object to a file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, object, saving-data

I have problems with **saving a Java Object to a file**. I'm writing the App with **Android Studio**.

Outgoing is the object which I want to save, it contains two `Strings`, and an `int`.

```
private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

public void save(String name, String category, int price){

    // Open file
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("outgoings.tmp");
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println(ioException.getMessage());
    }

    // Saving
    Outgoing record;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        try{
            if(name != null){
                record = new Outgoing(name, category, price);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(record);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            System.err.println(ioException.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Close file
    try{
        objectOutputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println(ioException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I am starting the app, execute the method `save()`, the app crashes.

```
// Open file
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("outgoings.tmp");
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    System.err.println(ioException.getMessage());
}
```

--> the IOException gets thrown and the Logcat shows me this:

[image: Logcat]

What would be a suitable File-Path & which datatype should I use?

**thank you for your help**

Comment: That it can't open the file....? Make sure that the current working directory is writable.

Comment: The obvious answer to your question is that the file can't be opened because of some issue.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the fact that you're serializing a class which has an object of another class in it.

Comment: I dont think you can create a relative file on Android, try to use a full-path to a file instead

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we can try to write in public directory so results can be easily checked with any file manager app.

Before writing to the filesystem ensure that `AndroidManifest.xml` contains two permission requests:

```
<manifest ...>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

...
</manifest>
```

We can proceed to writing files if your device or emulator/VM running Android 5 or below. If it is not, please take a look at the part of [android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java) about requesting permissions at runtime.

Here's some code that will give you writable directory with 95% probability:

```
File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Cool Folder");
destination.mkdirs();
```

So now you can try to write a file there

```
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination, "outgoings.tmp"));
//write there anything you want
```

Comment: Thank you. The saving works (It created file: "outgoings.tmp") in the created folder. How do I read this read this sequential file?

Comment: @PascalBurkard it's better for you to post another question about this according to SO rules :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the message `"Error opening file."` that means that the call to `openFile()` has failed:

```
public void openFile() {
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("outgoings.tmp");
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println("Error opening file.");
    }
```

The `ObjectOutputStream` constructor pretty much can't fail in this context, so the problem must be that `new FileOutputStream("outgoings.tmp")` threw the `IOException`, and the most likely explanation for that is that you don't have permission to create a file in the current directory.  (Other explanations are possible ....)

To get to the bottom of this, you need to modify your code to print or log the stacktrace for the `IOException`.

---

A couple of other points that should be made about this "beginner" code.

1. Doing this is a bad idea:

   ```
   } catch (IOException ioException) {
       System.err.println("Error opening file.");
   }
   ```

   Why?  Because after reporting the error, you are telling the code to continue as if nothing has happened.  And the next thing that you will try to do is to use `objectOutputStream` ... which has not been initialized!

   You should structure the code so that you **don't** continue after what **should be** treated as a fatal error by your code.
2. If you do this in real-life program that potentially opens files repeatedly, then you are liable to leak file descriptors.  The correct pattern for opening and using files (for Java 6 and later) is to use the "try-with-resources" construct; e.g.

   ```
   try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(...)) {
       // write stuff
   }
   ```

   when the body of the `try` ends, the resources that were opened at the start will be autoclosed.  This happens **in all circumstances that matter**.  By contrast, if you close resources manually, there is a risk that they won't all be closed in all circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I'm new, everybody has to start somewhere. I am understanding now why my exceptions where wrong. I edited my Question. Is it better now? what will solve my problem?

Comment: The stacktrace shows that you have gotten an NPE due to the code that I described as "doing this is a bad idea".  To solve your problem: 1) read my answer thoroughly so that you understand what I am saying, 2) fix the "bad idea" issue that I have pointed out.

Comment: The error message from the exception says "EROFS - read only file system".  Clearly, the place where you are trying to open the file is a read only file system.  Read-only means you can't write there!! Solution, 1) read the documentation for platform to find an appropriate directory path to write the file, 2) change your code to write to that directory ... not the current directory".

Comment: (3) Don't make up your own error messages. Print the exception.